# How to call a function from navigationbar in React native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, this

I am trying to create a screen where clicking on the title calls a function. 
The below code gives the error "undefined is not a function (evaluating _this2._test()"

When I define _test outside of the class Home, I can call the function (but _test can no longer access this.props).

Also, I am able to call the function _test from render() by using this._test.

It looks like this might be an issue with "this", but I can't figure out what the problem really is. Can someone please help?

```
@connect(data => Home.getDataProps(data))
export default class Home extends React.Component {

  static route = {
    navigationBar: {
      title: <Text onPress={()=>{this._test()}}>Home</Text>
    }
  }

  _test = () => {
    console.log("TEST SUCCESS")
    console.log(this.props)
  }
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats because your trying to call method from **static** object (more about static methods on this page: [MDN static](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static) ) which belongs to the class itself, not to the instance of the class. Maybe you should change `test()` method to be static also. You can't call non-static method from static method, however you can do opposite, call static from instance.

Moreover, the `<Text />` component is not being rendered inside your `<Home />` component. Thats why its a static object. And thats why you don't have access to `<Home />` component method by `this` operator. `This` operator point to the `route` object, not your component. Its just a configuration to list components that needs to be rendered.

You can establish `component to component` communication using for example redux actions.

I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish, but it would be good idea to use your own component instead of `<Text />` which can dispatch redux action while pressing the `<Text />` component. For example:

```
...
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import onTextPress from './redux/actions'
...

class MyText extends Component {

   render() {
     return (
       <Text onPress={() => this.props.onTextPress()} />
     )
   }
}

export default connect(null, { onTextPress })(MyText)
```

and of course connect your `<Home />` component to redux to handle changes occurred in redux store.

EDIT:
In your home component you have to modify `static route` object to use your new, custom component:

```
...
import MyText from './components/MyText'
...

export default class Home extends React.Component {

  static route = {
    navigationBar: {
      title: <MyText />
    }
  }
...
```

This will allow you to dispatch any action (in my example `onTextPress` action) from within navigation bar.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately, putting "static" before _test did not solve the problem, as I am still getting the same error. What I am trying to do is to dispatch an action from the Navigation bar. I noticed that I cannot do "this.dispatch" from the static route, which led me to creating the _test function to experiment with.

Comment: so you should create new component (look at my sample code above) and connect to the redux. This will allow you to dispatch the action. Then use this component instead of `Text` in `navigationBar`

Comment: Thank you! this makes sense